# I'm getting the following when trying to compile the Program

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am getting a mojofailure exception error.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project maven-war-plugin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[42,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[43,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[92,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[93,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[117,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\admin\Desktop\Virtual_class\src\main\java\com\iws\controller\LoginController.java:[117,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Check the source code of `LoginController` at line 117, column 31

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when you do not include the servlet-api.jar on your classpath. The servlet-api.jar is found in your container or application server.

For example, if you are running your application on Tomcat, be sure that tomcat is included on your classpath.

Comment: I have Included the servlet-api.jar. but the errors are not going.